# object hbase is not a member of package org.apache.hadoop when compiling scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, hbase

I am using HBase API in my scala project, but encounter a compile error when I import hbase

`import org.apache.hadoop.hbase`

the compilation result tells that "object hbase is not a member of package org.apache.hadoop"

I am using sbt to build my project, this is a part of the build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-core" % "1.2.1",
    "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase" % "0.99.2"
)
```

and I compile the project like this:
`sbt compile`

Have I missed something vital?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you need `hbase-client`, so you should also include this dependency:

```
"org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "0.99.2"
```

And possibly more, depending on what you're trying to compile.

Comment: It works ! I include `hbase-client`, `hbase-common` and `hbase-server`, then `sbt assembly` works correctly